# System.Web.UI.Control howto use on a page

Tags: asp.net, parsing, controls

I created a custom ASP.Net control:

```
namespace Chart2GoWeb.WebUI.UserControls
{
    public class NavigationBarControl : Control
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is time to use it on a aspx page.  I have tried adding:

```
<%@ Register Namespace='Chart2GoWeb.WebUI.UserControls' TagPrefix='c2gwwc'%>
```

to the page, and then used the control with this:

```
<c2gwwc:NavigationBarControl runat=server></c2gwwc:NavigationBarControl>
```

I am getting the error:

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'c2gwwc:NavigationBarControl'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please review it.

Answer (score 1):

`c2gwwc` should match the tag prefix `TagPrefix="asp"`

And shouldn't you extend WebControl and not Control? I'm not a pro but it doesn't look right.

Comment: First off I didn't post the correct Register, initially, I edited the post to correct it.  I tried making it a WebControl and that did not work.  I tried changing the correct Register to use the TagPrefix of asp, that didn't work.

Comment: Why didn't it work with a webcontrol? That *might* be your issue, since everything else that you've posted looks good to me

Comment: Same reason it didn't work as a Control: Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'c2gwwc:NavigationBarControl'.

Answer (score 0):

replace your custom asp control markup with this

```
<asp:NavigationBarControl runat=server></asp:NavigationBarControl>
```

**Updated Answer:**
If You have created a custom server control, Then you have to add the dll of your custom server control to your project. You can also add custom server control to your Toobox, right click on tool box, Choose Control or some thing like that,a new popup window will open, select your dll, then the control will appear in the toolbox.

Comment: Actually I posted the wrong Register line, here is the correct one: <%@ Register Namespace='Chart2GoWeb.WebUI.UserControls' TagPrefix='c2gwwc'%>  Are you saying that I should change the TagPrefix to asp?  I am assuming your comment comes from my mistype:)

Comment: your created a custom server control ? not a web user control am i right ?

Comment: The only thing this control does is overload Render() method, so I started it out as a System.Web.UI.Control, someone suggested I make it a System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl so I did.  Both gave me the same results.  FWIW: The control is in the same assembly as the aspx page.

Comment: have you assigned an ID to NavigationBarControl ? and one more thing what is Chart2GoWeb ? It is not a .net Class.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, all I had to do was add 'Assembly="Chart2GoWeb.WebUI"' to the Register and it worked.  It would seem that it does not assume the current assembly.  Live and learn.  Thanks for everyone's help.